# Using source control software without a locally running project

Tags: svn, version-control, remote-server

I need to use source control on a wordpress project I am working on, however, I cannot run the project locally. I tried to reproduce locally what I see on screen on the server and I failed. Initially, I thought of using Git, but since I cannot run the site locally, this is simply out of the question. What alternatives do I have in this case? Is there any version control software that would allow me to only checkout the files needed and not the whole project? Can Subversion do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make out what are you really asking: if I exert my telepathic skills hard enough I *think* I could read between your lines that in fact you want to employ a VCS as a sort of deployment tool, no?  I mean, you want it to allow you to just pull a file which needs editing off a live site and then accept its modified version automatically updating the site, no?

If that's what you really want then there's no real sense to use VCS: just use `FTP` or `SFTP` access via file mangers/text editors/IDE which support that (many many do), or use `rsync` to synchronize a local project directory with remote.

If, instead, you really want to make VCS help you with *development* of your code (that is, provide easy means for experimenting and supporting several versions of the same code being developed in parallel etc) then please stop thinking of VCS as a deployment tool.

I'd say go with Git for development and [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) for deployment.  This is *one way* though: you will have hard time reconciling your local project with changes manually done on the production system.  But this is solvable as well, just [search the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+web+development).

Comment: Apologies for not conveying my thoughts correctly. I must use VCS for proper development. BUT I cannot run locally what I see on the server. I get myriad of PHP errors when trying to view the Wordpress site through XAMPP. So I thought, I will have the site running on a test domain and use that for development. I shall check out only the files needed, edit them locally and see the results on the test domain. When I am done, I can copy the updated files to the live domain.

Comment: I don't know if this is simply the wrong approach, but what alternatives do I have now that I cannot experiment on my project locally?